# Jenkins PMD code analyzer warnings all show as high priority

Tags: jenkins, pmd

I am using Jenkins with PMD Plugin v3.45 and Static Analysis Collector plugin 1.48. Everthing is working correctly except that the reports show all warnings as **high** priority. If I check in the PMD output folder on the server, the reports do have the expected different warning priorities in the html output files correctly as configured in the ruleset.xml.

Furthermore, Jenkins Static Analysis Collector shows warnings as High, Medium, or Low. I am expecting a translation to be something like this:

PMD priority ==> Jenkins Priority

1 ==> High

2 ==> High

3 ==> Normal

4 ==> Normal

5 ==> Low

I have been searching all over where to configure it and cannot find it. Has anyone else faced this problem?

Answer (score 3):

Answering my own question - PMD.xml has a property:

If it is set to 2, only the priority or higher (1 or 2) will be reported.